# How to include Yii common data?

Tags: php, yii

I know how to include common functions in a helper class in Yii. But how about common data like drop down values? How can I access some common data in Yii without repeating inclusion in many files?
for example user type in database is varchar(1) and in code I define an array like:

> userTypes array 
>     'c' => string 'customer'  
>     'o' => string 'official  
>     'f' => string 'financial  
>     't' => string 'clearancer'  
>     'a' => string 'administrator'

there are lots of this stuff and I wanna know what's the best way t o handle it.

Comment: What kind of data? Can you show an example? In general, creating a custom model is a reasonable option.

Comment: Do you already have a `User` model, with an attribute that gets assigned these values?

Comment: I have a User model, but I do not know how to assign such values in User model!

Answer (score 3):

Due to the nature of PHP there's direct way to implement this. I do it by creating classes to store my common data, something like:

```
class GlobalData {
 const USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER = 'c';

 static function getUserTypes(){
   return array(
    'c' => string 'customer',
    'o' => string 'official',
    'f' => string 'financial,
    't' => string 'clearancer',
    'a' => string 'administrator');
 }
}
```

Then i use it like:

$userType =  GlobalData::getUserTypes();
echo $userType[USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER]; //To  display the usertype for a customer

But there's a [yii extension that let's you create enums](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/enum/) (to save time but works like i told you), you should check it out.

Hope this will help you, i'm not sure that this is what you wanted.

Comment: I do it similar. But for user types, i'd create a static method `optsType()` or `types()` in the `User` model.

Comment: Yes, your comment is the way to go to keep all model related data in the model.

Comment: that's ok, but in some older php versions like 5.1.6 there's no way to get an element like this: GlobalData::getUserTypes()['f'] and some time it's very important ro get directly an element of an array. for example in cgridview value of user type is a string that will be evaluate later, so it can not be fetched in one single command.